# What alternatives do I have for source control and does GIT does that?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, git, ipad

I work as a freelancer programmer for some clients and also create apps for myself. When I work for myself, obviously I work alone.

My big problems today are:

1. I have a lot of apps that use the same classes I have developed;
2. In the past, I put all these common classes on a directory outside all projects and included them on my apps using absolute paths, but this method sucks because by accident (if you forget) you may change a path or the disk and all projects are broken. Then I decided to copy those classes to my projects every time. Because the majority of these classes do not change frequently, I am relatively ok, but when they change, I am in hell;
3. When I change one of these classes I have to propagate the changes to all other apps using copies of them.

I have also tried to create frameworks but thanks to Apple, I cannot create frameworks for iOS and have to create libraries and bundles and create a nightmare of paths from one to the other and to the project to make that sh!t works. So, I am done with frameworks/libraries on Xcode until Xcode is a decent IDE.

So, I see I need something better to manage my source code.

What I need is this (I never used GIT on Xcode. I have read Apple docs but I still have these points):

1. does git locally on Xcode allows me to deal with assets or just code?
2. Can I have the equivalent of a "framework" (code + assets) managed by git locally?
3. Can an entire xcodeproj be managed as a unity? I mean, Suppose I have a xcodeproj created and want GIT to manage it, so I can include it on other projects.
4. How do I enable git on a project that was created without it and start designating files for management. (I have enabled git on Xcode's preferences, but all source control menu is grayed out).
5. supposing a bunch of files/assets are managed by GIT inside a project. Can they be used by other projects?
6. Is git the best option? Do I have another?

Remember that my main condition is that the files should stay on the local computer.

Please save me (I am a bit dramatic today).

Thanks.

Comment: Git isn't tied in with Xcode or anything like that. You can use it completely independently of any IDE if you so wish.

Comment: ok, but unfortunately I have to use Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want [git submodules.](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) These reference one repository from another.  And when that other repository changes, you can easily update things.

I wouldn't bother with frameworks or libraries here.  Once you have a submodule in your app that references your shared code, Xcode can just compile that source code on the fly.

Now to answer your specific questions:

> does git locally on Xcode allows me to deal with assets or just code?

Git stores binary assets as well as text (code) files.

> Can I have the equivalent of a "framework" (code + assets) managed by git locally?

Yep. Put shared code in it's own repository, then create a submodule that points to this repository in each project that uses this shared code.

> Can an entire xcodeproj be managed as a unity? I mean, Suppose I have a xcodeproj created and want GIT to manage it, so I can include it on other projects.

Not sure what you mean here.  But I would just worry about the source files, not the project file.

> How do I enable git on a project that was created without it and start designating files for management. (I have enabled git on Xcode's preferences, but all source control menu is grayed out).

I would not recommend using XCode source control tools. [Learn the command line interface](http://gitref.org/), or use the [GitHub mac app](http://mac.github.com/), or perhaps something like [Git Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/). Manage your source state outside Xcode, and leave Xcode to what it's good at: writing and compiling code.

> supposing a bunch of files/assets are managed by GIT inside a project. Can they be used by other projects?

See the link above on submodules, which allow one repository to include another.

> Is git the best option? Do I have another?

Git's great for this.  Repositories can be on only your computer, as well as on a remote server if you like. And they can reference each other, either by disk path or remote URL.

Git can do everything you have described. You just might want to avoid using Xcode's Git interface.  But I may just be an old fart that doesn't trust an IDE to manage source control.

Comment: I have tried that GitHub app and I was able to create a local git for a submodule. This is what I did: 1) I have created a folder with classes that work together 2) I have used GitHub and created that git for these files. I have looked the folder inside, and a .git directory was created with a lot of stuff. Now, it seems to be impossible to include this git on a project inside xcode. I followed one tutorial that said: go to your project's root path and type **git submodule add ~/Documents/GIT/MySubmodule** I did that and a folder called MySubmodule was created inside the project structure but

Comment: ... (cont)  ...  nothing was really added to the project inside xcode. Now what?

Comment: edit: the "empty" folder created inside the project's structure in fact is not empty. It contains a file named .git. Inside that file I find one line: gitdir: ../.git/modules/MySubmodule

Comment: If your submodule is empty, you probably just need to do a `git submodule update` at your command line.  I don't know that Xcode's Git UI has any support at all for submodules.

Comment: If I am not wrong, the WWDC 2013 video about git says "moving away from submodules"...

Comment: Well @RubberDuck, that sure sounds like a video you may want to watch.

Comment: Videos created by Apple are just showrooms of stuff, not a tutorial. They have a low value as a learning tool.

Comment: Ok, so don't watch it then.